# Can I use a Surface Pro 3 as a web server and install IIS/php?

Tags: windows, iis

I'd like to know if I can install IIS on a Surface Pro 3. I know the SP3 runs Windows 8, but I don't have a lot of experience setting up Windows servers so I'm not sure if there are any limitations.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can, you need to add IIS via Windows Features.

Full instructions from Microsoft can be found here:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/internet-information-services-iis-8-5

You then can add PHP using the Web Platform Installer, how do this can be found in the "how-to" section here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2819022